# The Hasse diagram below defines a partial ordering on the set {1,3,5,6}. Give the set of ordered pairs corresponding to this relation.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, order-theory

(Enter your answers as a comma-separated list of ordered pairs.)
My understanding is that in this diagram, every element is not connected to itself, and 3 is only connected to 5, 6, and 1.
I'm not sure why the answer isn't (3,5),(3,6),(3,1)
[Hasse diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8HLr.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming a below b means a < b,
the order would be {(1,3), (3,5), (3.6)}
with six more ordered pairs to assure
reflectivity and transitivity.